# Number of results not as it should be on boolean Solr query

Tags: search, solr, boolean

I have a Solr instance running with about 200 entries in its database. I want to search for strings with OR but fail to get a working query.

When running a simple query like this: `q=fieldname:"string"`, i get 13 results. When running another query like this: `q=fieldname:"otherstring"`, i gt 18 results. In the end i would expect it to be 27 results because together there are 31 results and 4 of the are the same ones as they contain both strings.

Problem now comes if i want to search both these strings at once it will return all kinds of results but not the expected 27. I found [this site](http://yonik.com/solr/query-syntax/) describing how it should work and tried a couple of different things:

- `q=fieldname:"string otherstring"` gives me 10
- `q=fieldname:"otherstring string"` gives me 0
- `q=fieldname:"string otherstring"~1` gives me 10
- `q=fieldname:"otherstring string"~1` gives me 1
- `q=fieldname:"(string otherstring)"` gives me 37 but some are not related at all
- `q=(+fieldname:"string" +fieldname:"otherstring")"` same as above

I could go on with this as i tried more if these combinations. Can anyone help me getting a query with the correct number of results or can anyone explain me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform an OR query, use OR explicitly:

```
q=fieldname:"string" OR fieldname:"otherstring"
```

The other versions will give varying results depending on the value `q.op` and the query parser in use.

```
q=fieldname:("string" OR "otherstring")
```

should be semantically identical.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with my Solr setup. I get 116 results running your exampes. Both of them.

Comment: Then it depends on what the field type is - and what's producing the matches. Have you looked at the output from debugQuery and checked the returned documents for WHY they're being returned?

Comment: Its a custom field type with EdgeNGramFilterFactory and some other filters.  Maybe that's the problem. I haven't tried debugging since it produces allot of output i don't understand. When i just tried it says allot but i cannot make any sense of it. What would be important to check for?

Comment: If you have a ngramfield, almost every single substring of the word will match against each other (especially if you're ngram-ing both on query and on indexing), giving you a (very) large amount of matches. This seems to behave as you'd expect for an NGram field?

Comment: I've chosen EdgeNGramFilterFactory to have exactly the results it produces since i use the search for autocomplete filters. It works like it should be for single strings but not with multiple ones and Boolean of any kind (AND or OR). I can even add additional fields with fq and it does work. My workaround would be to run multiple requests and filter duplicated returned results by ID.

Comment: are you ngramming on both index and query? What are the settings of your ngram field? What kind of tokenizer are you using? What do you expect for a certain query where there are multiple terms?

Comment: Sorry for long delay. We had to launch the search today with workaround but i would love to get the bug fixed. This is my config for the field: http://dpaste.com/12BMK5J
I am using this field for autocomplete search and any other string search. We have longer text fields and i want to be able to search for "an" and get results like "and", "anything", "ant" and so on. It all works very well for single strings.

Comment: Drop NGram-ing on query then - Since you're doing ngrams on query as well, you're searching for "a", "an", "and" if your query is "and". Since you are ngramming when you're indexing, you already have "a", "an" and "and" in your index, meaning that a search for "an" will give you the document back already. No need to ngram when querying.

Comment: Oh, i see. What would you suggest for query?

Comment: Sorry, i got you wrong! Just removing the filter made it work. Thanks allot. It works really great now! Sadly my reputation is not good enough for now to vote anything up.